# All POST/PUT requests have empty body in Outlook for iOS Add-In v. 2.62.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, outlook, outlook-web-addins

We're developing Outlook Web Add-In with the support of Outlook for iOS.
Recently we discovered horrible regression which was done in the web browser which hosts the Add-In:

All POST/PUT requests have an empty body in Outlook for iOS Add-In v. 2.62.0 - we see 0 in TotalBytes ASP.NET request property on ASP.NET Module level and also Content-Length header is 0 as well.

As a result, the whole Add-In functionality doesn't work and our production customers just struggle once again when using Cloud Add-Ins. We've got churn requests from many customers. It's just devastating experience.

Comment: What help are you looking for specifically? If this is a bug with a product, might it be worth logging that with the tech support for that product?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to a bug with webkit "https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=167131" which is fixed in iOS 11. Upgrade to iOS 11.